# DataGridView CellFormatting not formatting all specified cells

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have an SQL query that populates a DataGridView through a DataTable:

```
SELECT top 100 a.Ordnum, oldBFE, newBFE, oldCBRA, newCBRA, oldLOMC, newLOMC, oldfld,    newfld FROM 
(SELECT Ordnum, PrpBFE as oldBFE, CBRADte as oldCBRA, LOMCDte as oldLOMC, FldZne AS oldfld 
FROM [TOD].[dbo].[Orders] with (NOLOCK) WHERE RecRevDesc = '1 - Order Clone') a 
JOIN 
(SELECT Ordnum, PrpBFE as newBFE CBRADte as newCBRA, LOMCDte as newLOMC, FldZne AS newfld 
FROM [TOD].[dbo].[Orders] with (NOLOCK) WHERE RecRevDesc = '2 Determination Completed-Workflow') b 
ON a.Ordnum = b.Ordnum
```

If the value of certain pairs of cells are not equal, I need both cells to have a red forecolor. Right now, I am firing this through the cellformatting event:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.gridCompare.RowCount - 1
  If Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(1).ToString <> Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(2).ToString Then
    Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(1).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
  ElseIf Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(3).ToString <> Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(4).ToString Then
    Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(3).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(4).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
  ElseIf Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(5).ToString <> Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(6).ToString Then
    Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(6).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
  ElseIf Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(7).ToString <> Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(8).ToString Then
    Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(7).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(8).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
  End If
Next
```

However, only cells 1 and 2 have the correct formatting. What am I doing wrong? The order of the columns does not matter. I have tried individual IF statements as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the ElseIf branch since that will prevent testing the other pairs.  Put each test in it's own IF-EndIf.  You also need to test the Value property of the Cell:

```
If Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString <> _
   Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString Then
  'etc
End If

If Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString <> _
   Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString Then
  'etc
End If
```

Also, make sure those cells aren't null (or nothing) or else it will throw an exception.

Comment: When I change my if statement to:

    If Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString <> Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString Then
                Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(1).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If

I get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.



Also, null values are not an issue with the first two cells no matter what, the formatting is correct, it's just with subsequent cells @LarsTech.

Comment: @alybaba726 See my last sentence in the answer.  You have to check for null: `If Me.gridCompare.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value IsNot Nothing Then` etc.  Maybe the first two cells have empty strings.  Don't forget that the Cells are in 0 index order, so when you say "the first two cells", you are actually referring to cells 0 and 1 in the grid, not cells 1 and 2.

Comment: Yes, the first cell (0) is not included in the pairing, thanks for pointing that commonly overlooked error though. and yes, you are completely correct about the empty cells. I will fix it and I'm sure it will work perfectly. Thanks for seeing what I couldn't!

Comment: seriously @LarsTech, I could lick you if we were close enough, thank you major! I feel so silly now after knowing what went wrong.

Comment: @alybaba726 Interesting offer.  I'll settle for an upvote instead.  :-)